# Cordova javascript call

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am new to Cordova and I am trying to write a small aplication for mobile phone.
Problem is that I don't know how to call javascript functions from index.js. 
Idea is that img1 is shon for a second, then hide and img2 is shown..and redirect to second page..

```
  var app = {   
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
bindEvents: function() {
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
  },  
onDeviceReady: function() { 
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');   
},   
receivedEvent: function(id) {           document.getElementById("img1").hidden = true;      document.getElementById("img2").hidden = true;      document.getElementById("img3").hidden = true;              this.sendJavascript("init_move()");         
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
}
        setImageVisible: function (id, visible) {                   var img = document.getElementById(id);          img.style.visibility = (visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden');        }
        init_move: function () {                    setImageVisible('img1',false) ;             setImageVisible('img2',false) ;             setImageVisible('img3',false) ;
             var timeoutID = setTimeout(function()                {setImageVisible('img1',true);                                            var timeoutID = setTimeout( function() { 
                setImageVisible('img1',false) ;                             
                setImageVisible('img2',true) ;              var timeoutID = setTimeout( function() { 
                        setImageVisible('img2',false) ;                         
                        setImageVisible('img3',true) ;  
        var timeoutID = setTimeout( function() {
                        window.location.href = "index2.html" }, 1900);
                                    }, 600);                                                
                                        }, 600);                                            
                                    }, 600);
            }    app.initialize();
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean calling js function from index.js ?

Comment: I mean that js is located in index.js. Question is how to call function in index.js (function call another function for examp. onDeviceReady: function() { 
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready'); test();  
},  ) function test() {... /*recursion*/  test();}

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. My question is when is function fired, and how to call it? Standard javascript function is triggered on event onload=function(). How to do that in cordova? And how to create recursion?

Comment: You don't need to call any of these functions. As soon as you run the app and it becomes ready, it will fire an event 'deviceready' which will call "onDeviceReady" function and your code written in  'receivedEvent' function will be called at last which is being called from "onDeviceReady". hope this helps.